# Cannot find storage folder of LocalApplicationData

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm using SQLite in my Xamarin.Forms application. 
I created a .db3 database file in the LocalApplicationData folder. 
Now I want to check some things in the database file with a tool, but I cannot find(or access?) the folder where the file is located. 
When I output the path it says:
"/data/user/0/com.companyname.AppName/files/.local/share"
but it seems that the .local folder doesn't exist. 
Where can I find my database file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That folder will exist. But it is private to your app. So you cannot use other apps to look for it.

Comment: If you have UWP in your project you will be able to locate it in Windows and browse it.